# Determine if function is injective, surjective, bijective

Tags: functions, applications

For

$$f : \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$$

$$f(m,n) = 3m + 2n -1$$

I think it's injective, but don't know how to prove it. I've been trying numbers for m and n.

Comment: Compute $f(2,0)$. Then compute $f(0,3)$. What can you deduce?

Comment: Ok. it is not injective. Any trick did you use to find that combination?

Comment: I took at the definition of $f$ and then I thought a bit.

Comment: I started $f(m,n) = f(k,l)$. Then $3(m-k) = 2(l-n)$. This can be solved with $m-k = 2$ and $l-n = 3$. So, why not choose $k=n=0$ and $m=2$, $l=3$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function is not injective.
But it is surjective.

It is not injective, since $f(1,-1)=3-2-1=0$ and $f(-1,2)=-3+4-1=0$
$f$ is surjective:

Consider $f(0,n)=2n-1$ this gives us every odd integer immediatly. 
Now consider $f(1,n)=3+2n-1=2n+2=2(n+1)$ which gives us every even integer.

Answer (score 0):

It's surjective, but not injective. Take $(m_1, n_1)=(2, 0)$ and $(m_1, n_1)=(0, 3)$ and check yourself that $f$ yields te same output for both different inputs. For surjectivity, choose for chosen $z \in Z$, $(m, n)=((z+1)/3, 0)$ if $z+1=3k$, for a $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, choose $(m, n)=((z+1)/3, 1)$ if $z+1=3k-2$, for a $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, and chose $(m, n)=(0, (z+1)/2)$ if $z+1=2k$, for a $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.